# Minimized width for responsive website

Tags: html, css, web

I am building a responsive website. However, when I view it in a mobile mode, the content I have is just 50% of the screen and the rest is white space. May I know why?

[image]

Also, how can I make my background image of my home screen responsive? Sometimes it is responsive and sometimes its not.I don't know where I am going wrong.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide html/css of your current background image?

Comment: @ChrisJaquez  
    <div id="header" class="container">
 <div class="intro">
<h1>Welcome to Koffee King</h1>
<span><h3>Cup of a Coffee just a click away...</h3></span> </div>
 </div>

Comment: css
#header {
    background: url(../images/coffee_bg.jpg) center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    /*@@prefixmycss->No equivalent*/
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    /*@@prefixmycss->No equivalent*/
    background-attachment: fixed;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 600px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Check all the way through the white space for any div elements sticking out. There will be a div that extends the whole way across the page. Once that is altered to be the same width as the other content it will fit to the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the `<meta name="viewport">` tag.

Read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Try inserting this one first in the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```